# Device path using 'usb' lib

Tags: node.js, linux, usb

I'm using 'usb' lib in node.js env (https://www.npmjs.com/package//usb). Everything seems to be fine but what I really need to achieve is to get the device serial path. Is it possible to do that using lib above? I specifically mean to get something like: `/dev/ttyACM0`. I have access to the `busNumber`, `deviceAddress`, `portNumbers` but they're just numbers, is there anyway to convert them to something more meaningful?

Comment: Most USB devices of course are not serial ports, and many do not have paths.  If they do have a path, it will depend on the USB type. USB storage will have a path, but not a serial port path. These paths are OS-specific, at USB level they do not exist.

Comment: What do you need the device path for?  Can you find the name in /sys/class/tty?